# How can i remove a property from an object but keep its values?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how can I remove the `"formvalue1"` property from the following object but keep its children.

```
{
  "formvalue1": {
    "title": "sdf",
    "tname": "sdff",
    "taddress": "dfsdf"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you parsing a JSON file or has the JSON been converted to an object already?

Comment: @apena I changed it. I'll change it back

Comment: @apena It is already an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reassigning the object:

```js
let obj = {"formvalue1": { "title":"sdf", "tname":"sdff", "taddress":"dfsdf" } };
obj = obj.formvalue1;
console.log(obj)
```

If the original JSON is a string and not a JSON object. In javascript you can use `JSON.parse` to parse the string into an object literal (see comment below pointing out the discrepancy).

```js
const jsonStr = '{"formvalue1": {"title": "sdf", "tname": "sdff", "taddress": "dfsdf"}}'
let obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
obj = obj.formvalue1;
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: You're right, I assumed that was what he was referring to as the post had the javascript tag. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I just asked for clarification

Answer (score 0):

you use some `destructuring`

```js
const d = {
  "formvalue1": {
    "title": "sdssssssf",
    "tname": "sdff",
    "taddress": "dfsdf"
  }
}

const {
  formvalue1
} = d

const nd = formvalue1

console.log(nd)
```

Comment: Nice use of destructuring!